# How to know if a system is a rank deficient in linear least square?

Tags: least-squares

Let $\textbf{x} \in R^n$ be the parameter we want to find and $\textbf{b} \in R^m$ is the observation.

$$\textbf{Ax=b}$$

Sometimes observations (and $\textbf{A} \in R^{m\times n}$) are not enough to estimate $\textbf{x}$ or estimated parameters are less accurate. What is the metric to define the goodness of the observation?

Added:

Sorry for the missing details!

I am assuming the system is overdetermined. $m \gg n$

$(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}$ might exist but I am assuming that it could be nearly singular in which case the some of the estimated parameter $\textbf{x}$ is unstable. I am trying to detect which state parameter $\textbf{x}$ is less observed.

To give you more details, I have different methods that are used to create $\textbf{A}, \textbf{b}$. Some of the methods do not give enough observations to fully estimate $\textbf{x}$. As I have ground truth, I can say which one is the best but I would like to explain why some of they are not good by showing additional metric. For example

$$f(\textbf{A},\textbf{b},method_A)=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
100\\
50
\end{bmatrix}which\ means=\begin{bmatrix}
near\ singular\\
good\\
moderate
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$f(\textbf{A},\textbf{b},method_B)=\begin{bmatrix}
100\\
100\\
50
\end{bmatrix}which\ means=\begin{bmatrix}
good\\
good\\
moderate
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $f() \in R^n$.
In this example, method B is better.

I guess the title is confusing readers. Any recommendation for the title?

Added2:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 (\textbf{I}- {^L\textbf{R}_i})& \textbf{R} ^C\textbf{t}_i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textbf{t} \\ 
\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=
{^L\textbf{t}}_i
\end{equation}

Observations: $\textbf{R}, {^L\textbf{R}_i}\in SO3$,    ${^L\textbf{t}_i},{^C\textbf{t}_i}\in R^3$,

To be estimated: $ \textbf{t}\in R^3$, $\lambda \in R$. It is a displacement and scale estimation problem.

The observations ${^L\textbf{R}_i},{^L\textbf{t}_i},{^C\textbf{t}_i}$ are all noise currupted. Thus, if the observations are not spreaded enough, the estimation $ \textbf{t}\in R^3$ will be inaccurate.

Comment: I still don't really understand your edit. In particular it is not clear what your ground truth actually is, how you have it, the meaning of solving the problem when you have such a ground truth, etc.

Comment: @Ian The ground truth is coming from a simulation. Because real experiment does not have a ground truth, I am trying to prove the utility of my own method through a simulation first. It is a common practice in Robotics.

Comment: @Ian I added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the least squares problem for $Ax=b$ when $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},m>n$ and $A$ has rank $r<n$. In this case the least squares problem i.e. $\arg \min_x \| Ax-b \|$ does not have a unique solution; given one solution $x_0$ and any $n \in \mathrm{Ker}(A)$, $x_0+n$ is another solution.

Most commonly people define the solution in this case to be the solution of minimal Euclidean norm. Conveniently, this is also the solution that is provided by $(A^T A)^{\dagger} A^T b$, where $\dagger$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. This can be written in terms of the SVD as $V (\Sigma^T \Sigma)^\dagger \Sigma^T U^T b$, where the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a diagonal matrix is obtained by taking the reciprocal of each nonzero diagonal entry and preserving all zeros. Thus $(\Sigma^T \Sigma)^\dagger \Sigma^T$ is a $n \times m$ matrix whose entries are the reciprocals of the nonzero singular values of $A$ (on the diagonal) or zero.

Comment: Note the same solution is given by $\boldsymbol{A}^{+}\boldsymbol{b}$ (instead of  $\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{T}\boldsymbol{A}\right)^{+}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{b}$), where $^{+}$ denotes M.-P. pseudoinverse and is used in place of $^{\dagger}$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the least square solution is obtained for the projection

$$Pb=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$

therefore the error for the observation is goven by the vector

$$e=b-Pb$$

and a measure can be for example $\frac{|e|}{|b|}$ or $\frac{e^Te}{b^Tb}=\frac{|e|^2}{|b|^2}$.

In order to apply the method we need that $(A^T A)^{-1}$ exists that is the matrix $A$ is full rank columns. Therefore for $A_{m\times n}$ we need to check that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ and if $\operatorname{rank}(A)<n$ the system is rank deficent.

Comment: Presumably this is about the rank-deficient case in which $(A^T A)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Ian Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood the point! I add something on that.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I have added more details. Sorry for the confusion!